# What is powershell2.exe?

Tags: powershell, process

I have a process running on a server named **powershell2.exe**. It is not under the path where I would expect PowerShell to be running; instead it is deep in my **C:\Program Files** tree, within a folder associated with a trusted application (Splunk). My colleagues assure me that this isn't some sort of malware, but I'm wondering why there might be a need for an application to have such an executable present and running.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Does the file have a digital signature? Is it from Microsoft?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to be some Splunk-specific component, at least according to their blog: http://blogs.splunk.com/2013/09/09/powershell-version-2/

> My final advice is on errors. We now have two PowerShell hosts, each with different requirements. When installed on a standard Windows Server 2008R2 host with no updates, only **PowerShell2.exe** will be running because the .NET Framework 4.5 is not available. You will see errors in the splunkd.log pertaining to the inability to start the PowerShell.exe. In a similar manner, when installed on a standard Windows Server 2012 host, only PowerShell.exe will be running because the .NET Framework 3.5 is not available.

---

Note that this is probably a [PowerShell host](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706563.aspx) and not the runtime itself:

> You can host Windows PowerShell in your application. The host application can define the runspace where commands are run, open sessions on a local or remote computer, and invoke the commands either synchronously or asynchronously based on the needs of the application.

So it's very much a Splunk component and not part of the system. They just *chose* to name it `powershell2.exe`. They could have named it `cmd.exe` or `explorer.exe` *if they wanted*.

Comment: Many thanks; that is good enough an answer for me! I'll follow your link and read up on this business of "hosting PowerShell in your application" a little more, so I can focus my malware paranoia on something else.